# How to assign values to an object without directly typing out the object in R?

Tags: r, assign

Let's say I create a list using the `assign` function:

```r
name <- "test_list"
assign(name, list(a = c(1,2), b = c(3,4)))
```

Now, let's say I want to assign a new value to `test_list` without typing it out directly (like in a situation where I want objects with specific names to be generated automatically).

Both of the following attempts didn't work:

1.)

```r
as.name(name)$a[[1]] <- 5
```

2.)

```r
eval(expr = as.name(name))$a[[1]] <- 5
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
assign(name, `[<-`(get(name),  get(name)$a[1], 5))
```

Or make this more explicit

```
assign(name, {dat <- get(name); dat$a[1] <- 5; dat})
```

---

Or extract the object from the globalenv and assign

```
.GlobalEnv[[name]]$a[1] <- 5
test_list
#$a
#[1] 5 2

#$b
#[1] 3 4
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! A few quick follow up questions. Could you elaborate on how the first option works? I've never encountered the `[<-` syntax before. Also, is there an equivalent for ".GlobalEnv" for a functions "local" environment?

Comment: `environment()` is the current environment, but I think you probably want `sys.frame()` which accesses all frames of the calling environment.

Comment: @Nova The first. solution is not complete.  I modified it by explicitly assigning value.  You can create `new.env()` if you want to work in a specific env.  Also, check the option suggested by Ian

Answer (score 1):

One approach is with `eval(parse(text=expression))`, which can often be pressed into service in an emergency. But I would try to avoid it as much as possible.

```
name <- "test_list"
assign(name, list(a = c(1,2), b = c(3,4)))
eval(parse(text=paste0(name,"$a[[1]] <- 5")))
test_list
$a
[1] 5 2

$b
[1] 3 4
```